# C# Datatable linq - where any

Tags: c#, list, linq, datatable, any

I have a datatable that populates a list. The datatable has 3 columns, 'unit', 'clientId' and 'incident'. The incident could fx be '1. rate paid' or 'resold'.

I'm trying to exclude unit's from the list where any of it's incident is = 'resold', something like:

```
.Where(r => r.Field<string>("clientId") & r => r.Field<string>("unit").any() != resold))
```

This is my code:

```
var units = new List<string>();
if (showIndividualData == true)
{
    units = dt.AsEnumerable()
      .Where(r => r.Field<string>("clientId") == clientId)
      .Select(r => r.Field<string>("unit"))
      .Distinct()
      .ToList();
}
else
{
    units = dt.AsEnumerable()
      .Where(r => r.Field<string>("clientId").Length > 0)
      .Select(r => r.Field<string>("unit"))
      .Distinct()
      .ToList();
}
```

Comment: Hi, what is your question?

Comment: Edited the post for more specific information. 'clientId' is also a column in the datatablle.

Comment: The question is how can I check if any row with the given unit has a incident of resold

Comment: You posted some code that appears to try to accomplish that. Did you try it? What was the result?

Comment: This code just selects the unit where the clientId matches. But I need another filter that checks if any of the units incident is is = resold

Answer (score 0):

Here's a sample of a working solution. I assumed all string fields but you get the idea. I have also commented each line to explain the process of the linq for easier understanding if you have difficulties.

```
// some dummy table i assume you have filled
var dt = new DataTable();

// arbitrary client if, you can alter the beginning of the linq for your multi client query somehow
var clientId = "some client";

// the important linq syntax
var units = dt.Rows.Cast<DataRow>() // as datarow array
                   .Where(dr => dr["ClientId"].ToString() == clientId) // filter client
                   .GroupBy(dr => dr["unit"].ToString()) // group by unit for easy conditional after
                   .Where(grp => grp.ToList().All(dr => dr["incident"].ToString() != "resold")) // filter each group and keep only those where all the records are not "resold"
                   .Select(grp => grp.Key).ToList(); // select the key of the groups which is the "unit" column and already filtered
```

Answer (score 0):

One can use the `Any` with the predicate you mentioned...just change it to

```
&& r.Field<string>("unit").Any(itm => !itm.Equals(resold))
```

and that will help discriminate it in your `Where` clause.